# Error on activating CSRF protection

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm getting the following error message when I set `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;`:

> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in /opt/codeigniter/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 369
>   A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Class 'CI_Controller' not found Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php Line Number: 369 Backtrace:

I'm following the [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf), but I can't see clear cause for it.

By the way, it only happens when I try (by <kbd>F5</kbd>) to reload a FORM submitted with `POST`. I know that an error is expected, but I think that it should be shown in an error page (or something), and might be another kind of error.

Anyone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is that I modified the *views/errors/error_general.php* to dynamize reporting responses getting variables from CI instance, then, someway, the error response from CSRF protection become misconfigured.

Apparently, this file can not see CI instance, so it is not possible to use instance references in it.

This was fixed by returning the file *views/errors/error_general.php* to the original version, but I'm still studying ways to customize it.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Have you ever found a proper solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, @kobus-myburgh. And we migrated to CI4, so we stopped trying.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correctly named your files and class names https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming

For CSRF

I find it's best to create a vHost for your project once that done domain like example

```
example.com
```

config.php

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = 'ci_';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '.example.com';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;


$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

And use the form helper [functions](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#available-functions) That fixed it for me.

Comment: It is already done. I am using all these settings, but it still does not work properly. I suspect that is something related to my error reporting settings...