# Codeigniter 3 system - enabling CSRF protection causes a fatal error CI_Controller not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, exception

I am working on a system built on CodeIgniter 3, and there was a request to enable CSRF on login and registration forms.

In my config file, I have done:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
if (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
    if (stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/login') !== FALSE || stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '/register') !== FALSE ) {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
    }
}
```

But the moment I try to set `csrf_protection` config variable to true, my error handler is triggered that a function does not exist. The function does exist in my `MY_url_helper` and the error is misleading in that it actually complains about this function not being found first, but the actual error is that `CI_Controller` is supposedly not found, initially leading me to believe that the CodeIgniter instance is not being recognised, even though the backtrace indicates otherwise:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => path\to\system\core\Exceptions.php
            [line] => 268
            [function] => include
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => path\to\system\core\Common.php
            [line] => 627
            [function] => show_php_error
            [class] => CI_Exceptions
            [object] => CI_Exceptions Object
                (
                    [ob_level] => 1
                    [levels] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => Error
                            [2] => Warning
                            [4] => Parsing Error
                            [8] => Notice
                            [16] => Core Error
                            [32] => Core Warning
                            [64] => Compile Error
                            [128] => Compile Warning
                            [256] => User Error
                            [512] => User Warning
                            [1024] => User Notice
                            [2048] => Runtime Notice
                        )

                )

            [type] => ->
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Error
                    [1] => Uncaught Error: Class "CI_Controller" not found in path\to\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:369
Stack trace:
#0 path\to\app\core\MY_Exceptions.php(54): get_instance()
#1 path\to\system\core\Common.php(195): MY_Exceptions->__construct()
#2 path\to\system\core\Common.php(656): load_class('Exceptions', 'core')
#3 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error))
#4 {main}
thrown
                    [2] => core/CodeIgniter.php
                    [3] => 369
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [file] => path\to\system\core\Common.php
            [line] => 693
            [function] => _error_handler
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => Uncaught Error: Class "CI_Controller" not found in path\to\system\core\CodeIgniter.php:369
Stack trace:
#0 path\to\app\core\MY_Exceptions.php(54): get_instance()
#1 path\to\system\core\Common.php(195): MY_Exceptions->__construct()
#2 path\to\system\core\Common.php(656): load_class('Exceptions', 'core')
#3 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error))
#4 {main}
thrown
                    [2] => path\to\system\core\CodeIgniter.php
                    [3] => 369
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [function] => _shutdown_handler
            [args] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

I am very confused about how it does not work if by all indications that I can see, CodeIgniter is loaded. The code base has extended the CI_Exceptions class, and here is the constructor as I have it now for testing:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        die('Error is showing');
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        die('Error not showing');
    }
}
```

Somehow, when the instance is being assigned, all goes pear shaped.

This question: [Error on activating CSRF protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41780954/error-on-activating-csrf-protection?rq=2) provides some information that looks the same, but the accepted answer is not really an answer that I can implement.

Setting my CI error logging to level 4 (all messages) gives me this:

```
INFO - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> URI Class Initialized
INFO - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2023-10-06 13:47:57 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
```

No errors in this log whatsoever.

Any ideas?

Comment: this is setup as such?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76178617/how-to-enable-csrf-protection-in-codeigniter-3-and-use-the-get-csrf-hash-fun  IMO that I've never used this, I used session based cookies and always checked the user was valid and logged in before doing any user profile stuff, else they got kick redirected to the login page.

Comment: Hi, yes, it is like that but with conditional enabling, not enabling for all forms. The rest of your comment does not apply to my situation. This is not about redirecting to the appropriate place, but about preventing cross-site request forgery (CSRF).

Comment: You can roll your own Anti-CSRF by creating hidden token on a form and in a user session cookie. Then compare both on submit to match ok, And only on the forms where you need this security. The redirect I mentioned was only when the check fails. Cheers.

Comment: @MTMDev - if you are having this issue, then see my answer below - finally got something working, albeit inelegant, and breaking some rules...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a very inelegant fix (also going against best practices, but for the lack of a better solution, this will have to do).

It appears that CodeIgniter 3 CSRF/Security implementation at one stage calls the `get_instance()` procedural function before the class that it requires to fulfil the request, is initialized. It seems to happen in some sort of loop, because it fails only the first time, then the class required seems to be initialized, and the second time onwards it works. It is the best explanation I can think of - might be totally off base, but my fix works.

**NOTE:**: I know not to change the system's core files, and I understand the logic around it, but this is not a class. It is procedural code, so can't extend it. I then tried to adjust and extend the class that is referenced, but that became messy real quick - so I am open to suggestions if someone has a better solution.

Changing `system\core\CodeIgniter.php` from this:

```
function &get_instance()
{
    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

To this:

```
function &get_instance()
{
    if (class_exists('CI_Controller')) {
        return CI_Controller::get_instance();
    }
}
```

Solves the problem for me without any further issues, and CSRF working as expected. It appears as if the first time this `get_instance()` method is called, the class is not yet initialized. The backtrace did not give me enough information to trace where this actually happens.